# Minimum Crew of Soyuz TMA-M

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, crew-size

Is there a NASA or a Roscosmos safety guidelines or something, stating the minimum crew required to safely operate the TMA-M? I.e. get it into orbit and safely re-enter.

Answer (score 5):

In theory 0, as the spacecraft can be [remotely controlled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz-TMA#Soyuz_TMA-M) by the Teleoperated Control Mode present in all Soyuz spacecraft. This has not been used beyond a few rendezvous tests though, so an onboard pilot is still recommended.

Comment: I personally wonder if a crew of 2 is allowed. No way to simultaneously man the commander seat and keep the weight distributed evenly. (unless maybe you shift some payload to the spare seat).

Comment: Is is possible two have 2, and yes, the unoccupied place will be used for extra baggages. This was an option, when Sarah Brightman cancelled her trip.