# Potential catastrophic death on the ISS from mistakes

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, death

Other than from decompression and fire, what other ways has NASA or the Russian space program identified unique ways someone on the ISS could die suddenly, in particular from human error with the technology of the station.

I understand micrometeors and debris from artificial satellites are always a threat, but those wouldn't be caused by an error on the station.

Addendum-A heart attack; choking with piece of food; losing too much blood from a cut of a major artery, are not unique to errors with the technology of the station.

Comment: You're looking for a PRA (probabilitistic risk assessment) skinnied down to human error causes. I've seen PRAs for shuttle but not ISS. Doesn't mean they don't exist, of course.

Comment: A heart attack; choking with piece of food; losing too much blood from a cut of a major artery, etc.

Comment: It appears that an ISS PRA was done http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2002ESASP.486..319S  but the article doesn't go into a lot of detail. If it can be found, the answer to your question would be in there.

Comment: @LeoS Thank you for helping clarify the question.

Comment: There are some particularly high voltages in the power production system (solar panels, batteries) on the ISS. There are likely ways to be electrocuted if a power component is damaged or mishandled.

Comment: [This](https://scientificrussia.ru/articles/iss-year-risks) article (in Russian), along with fire and decompression, highlights risk of major malfunction of life support system(s) and presence of toxic atmosphere (both could be induced by a human error). I would also add a possibility of human error in handling dangerous bio- experiments (outbreak of hazardous bio- material of a bio-experiment to the ISS habitat atmosphere), but these scenarios are unlikely to lead to a *sudden* death though. Saying this, there are terminal scenarios when fire or decompression wouldn't lead to a *sudden* death

Comment: Astronaut Luca Parmitano nearly drowned during a space walk...

Comment: @Paul not germane - no human error

Comment: True it is not germane but it was helpful to me anyway.  It answered a question I didn't even think to ask.

Comment: here's some non-germane human error: [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33097/12102), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30451/12102), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30501/12102), [4](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30393/12102) I suppose something similar could be done by an astronaut on the ISS as well.

Comment: Two circumstances I can think of: crashing a spacecraft into the station by botched rendez-vous (like it happened with Mir, dumb luck nothing critical was damaged), and a space-suit failure during EVA (due to an error in handling or inspection failure). Drowing in the coolant water due to a leak in the cooling layer is a serious risk and something that almost happened (the leak wasn't so severe as to obstruct the astronaut's mouth and nose)

Comment: No timely supplies from earth accompanied by an absence of functioning return vessels. A lab rat going berserk. A "flight participant" space tourist going berserk and unauthorisedly run some technological devices, such as Soyuz.

Comment: Flying away from the station during EVA because of a detached tether?

Comment: Smashed by moving parts (such as Strela or Canadarm cranes) during EVA?

Comment: @CourageousPotato Voltages used on the ISS are not higher than those used in houses equipped with solar panels. Voltages used for outdoor power distribution on Earth for medium and long distances are much higher.

Comment: @Uwe I meant high voltage in the solar panel assembly itself

Comment: Absence of return vessels is very unlikely. There's always enough to return and preparing a Soyuz for launch takes less than supplies will last, plus Dragon 2 is practically ready and can be prepared for flight in weeks. Flying away from station - SAFER maneuvering system, plus they can always give a chase in a Soyuz. The speeds would hardly exceed 2-3 m/s. Plus you'd need a very bad accident to lose the tether, the loads are really low in 0g. Canadarm moves quite slowly, would be hard to get hit strong enough.